# Flurry ads not showing on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ads, flurry

I have followed all the descriptions and directions on the website to integrate FlurryAnalytics and FlurryAppCircle. Analytics is showing information but there are no ads getting displayed on any of the views I have created.

In Application Delegate I did this as described:

```
/* FLURRY APP-CIRCLE INTEGRATION CODE*/
[FlurryAppCircle setAppCircleEnabled:YES];

/* FLURRY ANALYTICS INTEGRATION CODE*/
[FlurryAnalytics startSession:@"MY_API_KEY_HERE"];
```

and then in a view controller at view did load I added:

```
[FlurryAppCircle setAppCircleDelegate:  self];
hook = [FlurryAppCircle getHook:@"BuddyTracker_Default_Ad" xLoc:0 yLoc:0 
    view:self.view attachToView:YES orientation:@"portrait" 
    canvasOrientation:@"portrait" autoRefresh:YES canvasAnimated:YES 
    rewardMessage:nil userCookies:nil];

//where view is UIView.
```

- Now in FlurryAppDelegate the method `- (void)dataAvailable` is getting
  called but there is no ad added (possibly as a subview) to this view.
- I also tried looking at the `hook` variable when data is available
  but it is `nil`.
- One thing strange is that when I call
  `getHook:@"BuddyTracker_Default_Ad"` again in the `dataAvailable` method 
  the ad magically appears.

I am not sure what is happening here. Could someone please suggest what should I do so that advertisements get added to the view automatically when loaded?

Comment: Did you solve this in the end?

Comment: Hi JamesC. It is very old post, I dont even remember how I solved this :) As far as I remember I used an alternate method to this, the one not involving getHook.

Comment: Solved it now by using a delegate which has operations that get fired when Ads are ready..basically it was a timing issue. Thanks